# Change x:y to x ↵ y

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following problem: In my very large excel spreadsheet, I have a few rows that look like this:

| Memo: IBRD |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IDA |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

and a few others that look like this:

| Memo: |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IBRD |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| IDA |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want them to be uniform and change all those that exhibit the first format to the SECOND one (where Memo: empty; and the next row is IBRD with the data entries).

I have found the following VBA code that might do the trick but I am not 100% how to apply this to my problem here.

```
Sub splitOneCellIntoMore()
Dim R As Range
Dim I As Range
Dim O As Range
wTitle = "splitOneCellIntoMoreCells"
Set I = Application.Selection.Range("B")
Set I = Application.InputBox("Select the Cell B1 that contains the text you want to split:", wTitle, I.Address, Type:=8)
Set O = Application.InputBox("Select destination cell you want to paste your split data:", wTitle, Type:=8)
A = VBA.Split(I.Value, ":")
O.Resize(UBound(A) - LBound(A) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(A)
```

End Sub

(I took the code from: https://www.excelhow.net/split-one-cell-into-two-or-more-cells.html)

This is the table I am using.

```
| DEBT OUTSTANDING(LDOD)                                              |  |   |   | 36 | 330 | 405 | 412 | 527 |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------- |--|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| Public and publicly e;uaranteed                                     |  |   |   | 36 | 330 | 405 | 412 | 506 |
| Official creditors                                                  |  |   |   | 2  | 305 | 376 | 385 | 480 |
| Multilateral                                                        |  |   |   | 0  | 115 | 151 | 164 | 242 |
| Concessional                                                      I |  |   |   | 0  | 110 | 142 | 155 | 232 |
| Bilateral                                                           |  |   |   | 2  | 190 | 225 | 221 | 238 |
| Concessional                                                        |  |   |   | 2  | 151 | 189 | 190 | 212 |
| Private creditors                                                   |  |   |   | 34 | 25  | 29  | 27  | 26  |
| Bonds                                                               |  |   |   | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| Commercial banks                                                    |  |   |   | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| Other private                                                       |  |   |   | 34 | 25  | 29  | 27  | 26  |
| Privatenone;uaranteed                                               |  |   |   | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 21  |
| Bonds                                                               |  |   |   | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
| Commercial banks and other                                          |  |   |   | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 21  |
| Memo: IBRD                                                          |  | 0 | 0 | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0   | 0   |
|                                                                     |  |   |   |    |     |     |     |     |
| IDA                                                                 |  | 0 | 0 | 0  | 109 | 137 | 148 | 220 |
| DISBURSEMENTS                                                       |  |   |   | 33 | 70  | 90  | 52  | 89  |
| Public and publicly e;uaranteed                                     |  |   |   | 33 | 70  | 90  | 52  | 89  |
```

Comment: No, there is not a quick function that will change them all at once. Why do you feel that a quick function is important here? And what does "quick" mean to you? Quick to write? Quick to call? Quick to implement?

Comment: You can use autofilter and change them all at once. Filter rows containing BRD and you will get both IBRD and Memo BRD rows. Then you can change them

Comment: Thanks, Naresh; highly appreciated! Ill try that

Comment: Hey @Enigmativity, thanks for your comment! Ill try to be a bit more precise next time. I guess what I meant was a VBA code that would simply replace the one format with the other. Thanks

Comment: @gregthenovelist VBA code never just exists, it always has to be written for the specific task you want to do. Therefore asking if a code exists is off-topic on SO. Because it is either asking others to do the work for you (SO is no free code writing service). Or it is asking for off-site resources (off-topic according [help]). Actually SO is meant to help people who have issues with code they have written and need assistance to fix it. Therefore you always need to show what you have tried and researched yourself before asking. See the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @gregthenovelist - It isn't a formatting exercise. You need to insert a line and split the text across two lines.

Comment: Need to know where B in relation to screenshot is.

Comment: 1) Is the table at the bottom supposed to correlate/correspond to the screenshot rows you have at top? 2) What exactly do you mean when you say "I want them to be uniform and change all those that exhibit the first format to the SECOND one" - do you basically want to populate the second instance of three rows with data from your table? 3) do you need to have this done using VB? 3b) if not, do you have Office 365? REQUEST: could you recreate the screenshots using tables to save up time this side in trying to reproduce your problem  pls?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little lost re: how the table at bottom is supposed to relate to the screenshots at the top - e.g. IDA has 0,0 (which looked promising given your screenshot), but then another 0 followed by 109, - which doesn't correspond to your screenshot for this field (viz, '0','0', '2','0','0' etc.) so Q not v. clear I'm afraid).

Comment: Firstly, apologies to all those who downvote my post. I know that it isnt up to the standard of the forum yet but it is also my second post and your comments help me to avoid mistakes for the next one.

Comment: @JB-007, 1) yes, the screenshot corresponds to the table at the bottom. On the table at the bottom, you can see "Memo: IBRD", I would like to shift the IBRD and the respective values in the row down as seen in the second screenshot. 2) I mean that in the current table, I have both appearances (as seen in screenshot 1 and 2). I would like to change all the appearances where "Memo: IBRD" to "Memo (next row) IBRD. In sum, in my excel sheet, there are two instances like in the screenshots; I want to get rid of all the first instances and change them to the second.

Comment: @JB-007, 3) no VB is not necessary, I just thought it would be. If you have a better idea on how I can change that , I would be happy to take your idea on board and try it. I have office 365 on a mac. Request: sure! sorry for that

Comment: regarding your last point: please ignore the values. it is just about the text at the beginning: the values dont align, I just wrote them in Excel and took a screenshot of them. The only point where the values come into play is that when the Memo and IBRD is seperated, the values should go with the IBRD rather than with "Memo". Hope that clarifies this. sorry for the confusion

Comment: @gregthenovelist hi thanks for coming back to me - I'm prepared to proffer a non-VB soln but fear I may not be addressing exactly what you're after - giving I can ignore the values in the table below vs tables above (thanks for replacing screenshot).  Pretend we had a single cell that contained the following: a | b | c | d.  Would it suffice if I showed you a quick way (purely function driven) to spill this (or any other length with this / other delimiter) so that you had a, b, c, and d in 4 separate cells (i.e. purely 'split' them)?  Would entail filterxml - compatible with your excel?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot/[link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98B-9HqLU7eJ1YGoI?e=Du7w1j) refer:

Use FilterXML to split cells as follows:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,"|","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")),"")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I really appreciate your help; thanks for that. The problem is that I am very imprecise even though I thought that I made the problem clear. I do have to raise my problem-stating skills.

Comment: I try it one last time: on your second table (where the values are all perfectly arranged) you can see in line 17 that it states "Memo: IBRD". What I try ask is: How can I split this "Memo: IBRD" into "Memo" and "IBRD" and simultaneously shift "IBRD" and the 0s from column M-S down to the empty row. The outcome should be: Memo: (all other columns in this row empty); and in the next row: IBRD with the zeros from the row before. At this point, it might just be the case that there is no solution and that I have to do all of this by hand. However, I won't give up my last hope. thanks again